# Element type "firstname" must not be declared more than once?

Tags: xml, dtd

**This is the error i get while generating DTD for this XML document**

```
Element type "firstname" must not be declared more than once line no. 21
```

**Question:** This is the given XML Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE order SYSTEM "order.dtd">

<order number="1">

<shipto>

    <reference customer="C001"></reference>

</shipto>

<contact>Tom</contact>

<date>

    <day>14</day>

    <month>06</month>

    <year>2017</year>

</date>

<item>

    <book>

        <isbn>1547895</isbn>

        <title>Introduction to XML</title>

        <price>1490</price>

        <author>

            <firstname>Ivan</firstname>

            <lastname>charles</lastname>

        </author>

    </book>

    <quantity>4</quantity>

    <discount>5</discount>

</item>

<item>

    <book>

        <isbn>1547885</isbn>

        <title>Java Programming</title>

        <price>2000</price>

        <author>

            <firstname>James</firstname>

        </author>

    </book>

    <quantity>4</quantity>

    <discount>5</discount>

</item>

<person id="C001">

    <firstname>Tom</firstname>

    <lastname>Richard</lastname>

    <address>

        <company>ABC</company>

        <city>Bangalore</city>

        <addressline>Electronic city</addressline>

    </address>

</person>

</order>
```

**Code:** This is the code I have implemented for generating DTD from the XML document given above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT order (shipto,contact,date,item+,person)>
<!ELEMENT shipto (reference)>
<!ELEMENT reference (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT contact (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date (day,month,year)>
<!ELEMENT day (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT month (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT item (book+,quantity+,discount+)>
<!ELEMENT book (isbn+,title+,price+,author+)>
<!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (firstname+,lastname*)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>                       \\line number 21
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT discount (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT person (firstname,lastname,address)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT address (company,city,addressline)>
<!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT addressline (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST order number ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST reference customer CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST person id ID #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: yes i got it what you said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says, you can [only declare an element once](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-elementdecl).

In your DTD, you have declared `firstname` and `lastname` twice.

Even though both `author` and `person` allow firstname/lastname in their content models, you can only declare them once. If you remove one `firstname` declaration and one `lastname` declaration your DTD will be valid.

Also, in your XML, the `number` attribute value on the `order` element is [invalid because it starts with a number](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#id).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT order (shipto,contact,date,item+,person)>
<!ELEMENT shipto (reference)>
<!ELEMENT reference (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT contact (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date (day,month,year)>
<!ELEMENT day (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT month (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT item (book+,quantity+,discount+)>
<!ELEMENT book (isbn+,title+,price+,author+)>
<!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (firstname+,lastname*)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT discount (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT person (firstname,lastname,address)>
<!ELEMENT address (company,city,addressline)>
<!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT addressline (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST order number CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST reference customer CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST person id CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

THIS IS THE CORRECTED CODE. PLEASE CHECK